# JavaGD fails to load

Tags: r

Could someone please help.

I had Deducer working with R 2.14 but now that I have updated to 2.15.1 I can't get JGR to load. I have loaded JGR and Deducer.

This is the message I get when installing

```
Loading required package: JavaGD
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'JavaGD', details:
  call: .Call("RegGetStrValue", c(key, "CurrentVersion"), PACKAGE = "JavaGD")
  error: C symbol name "RegGetStrValue" not in DLL for package "JavaGD"
Error: package ‘JavaGD’ could not be loaded
```

I have removed all old versions of R and Ver 2.15.1 - reinstalled R and still get this message.

Is it possible that this is a Registry problem and if so where should I look.

I have searched and although there seem to be simiar reported issues, none are exactly the same from the ones that I have seen. I certainly dont seem to have m,ultiple versions of JavaGD in  my library and the Namesake file is in the folder JavaGD.

I am running Win 7 32 bit ver on fairly current Dell Laptop.

R seems to work fine and I am using R-Studio most of the time and that works fine as well.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that a new version of JavaGD is making it's way through CRAN right now. try installing version 0.6-1 with install.packages("JavaGD",repos="http://cran.r-project.org",type="source"). Note RTools must be installed to install from source.

Comment: Thanks Ian as well as the tip regarding RTool, I'll give it try when I get a moment.

Comment: Hi Ian, I installed RTools using all the default paths etc and then used your recommended JavaGD install line which then came back with the following message, any reccommendations as to what I am missing. I have never had neeed to use RTools so I am not sure besides installing it whether I need to do anything else. install.packages("JavaGD",repos="cran.r-project.org",type="source")
Warning: unable to access index for repository cran.r-project.org/src/contrib Thanks Steve
Warning message:
package ‘JavaGD’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)

Comment: looks like stack overflow interpreted my code as a link. you need to add http://

Answer (score 0):

7 years on form the OP's original issue choosing the right Java Download is critical for 64-bit machines which most of our RStudio environments are synced to work with. For whatever reason, downloading the 64-bit JRE is difficult. To avoid the same error presented by Deducer more recently be sure to download the 64-bit Java JRE from https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp. Note, the 64-bit version must be downloaded offline as instructed (usually bottom of Windows downloads). Check that the installation path is c:\Program Files\Java and not c:\Program Files(x86)\Java. That plus the JDK should fix this problem going forward.